# Earth Engine: feature collection will not export even in chunks

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to export zonal statistics from the Worldpop dataset for about 450,000 0.01° tiles, but I can't get it to work. When I break the data into chunks of 50,000 observations, the computation still times out on each.

My tiles were imported into GEE (anyone can read):

```
var tiles = ee.FeatureCollection('users/salem043/deforSample');
```

I mosaicked the country-year data in Worldpop together to produce annual images:

```
var years = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2012)
// Make some band names from the years numbers.
var yearBandNames = years.map(function(n) { return ee.Number(n).format("pop_%d") })

var yearImages = ee.ImageCollection(
  years.map(function(year) {
    var oneYear = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
      .filterBounds(tiles)
    return oneYear.mosaic()
  }))
  .toBands()
  .rename(yearBandNames)
```

Then to produce the data frame, I select the year image and perform a reducer function to get the zonal statistics. I perform the same function as defined below for all years 2001-2012:

```
var pop_2001 = yearImages.select("pop_2001");

var sumPop_2001 = tiles.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.set(pop_2001.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: feature.geometry(), scale: 30
  }));
});
```

I tried exporting this data in chunks of 50,000 tiles at a time, but each computation timed out. Can anyone offer advice as to how to make this program more efficient so that it exports? Full code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fsalem043%2FARC%3AWorldpop%20export)

Answer (score 0):

First, since the scale of your raster is 100 meters, set the scale in `reduceRegion` to 100.

Then, if you do the same for every year and every tile, why not map over the Image Collection instead of calling `.toBands()` and use `reduceRegions()` instead of `reduceRegion()`.

Something like this should work (haven't tested it):

```
var yearImages = ee.ImageCollection(
  years.map(function(year) {
    var oneYear = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
      .filterBounds(tiles)
    return oneYear.mosaic().set('system:index', ee.String(year))
  }))

var sumPop = yearImages.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: tiles, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
    scale: 100
  })
});
var flat = sumPop.flatten()
```

It might still time out, since 450,000 is quite a lot, but like this you should have a better chance.

Comment: This is helpful - thank you! But is the mapping reducer still missing something? The function only produces one zonal statistic: It should produce multiple, for each year.

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately I can't try out the code quickly since you didn't give access to your script

Comment: Perhaps the link to my script was not working earlier? I just edited the original post, updating the link to the script. It should work now.

Comment: It's best to give access by using the `Get Link` button in the code editor, try it this way

Comment: I just tested it and everything is working. I only changed my answer a bit, to show from which year what is coming from. If it still isn't clear I would need more info about your `tiles` asset to help further.