# Mapping over a reduceRegions command in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, zonal-statistics, reducers

I have a feature collection of about 80,000 tiles, and I am trying to calculate the annual maximum drought severity index score for each tile using TerraClimate data. TerraClimate is an image collection, so I started by transforming it into a stack of images.

```
var drought_M = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").select("pdsi")
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2012-12-31'));

//This function creates a stack of images from the image collection
function newCollectionToImage(collection){
    var stack = ee.Image(collection.iterate(function(img, prev) {
        return ee.Image(prev).addBands(img);
    }, ee.Image(1)));
 
    stack = stack.select(ee.List.sequence(1, stack.bandNames().size().subtract(1)));
    return stack;
}

//This function renames the image collection bands
var drought_M_rename = drought_M.map(function(img){
var y = ee.String(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).get("year"));
return img.set("year",y).rename(y);
});

//Apply the function to create a stack of images
var droughtImageStack = newCollectionToImage(drought_M_rename);
```

I tried to use reduceRegions() to get the monthly score for each tile.

```
var droughtImageStack = tchImg.reduceRegions(tiles, ee.Reducer.mean());
```

This works in the terminal, but when I try to export the dataframe as a csv, GEE returns the error:

```
Error: User memory limit exceeded.
```

I've been told before that image reductions become a lot more efficient when you map over the feature collection. I tried to use the basic intuition of how to map over a feature collection for reduceRegion() and attempted the following:

```
var droughtTiles = tiles.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.set(droughtImageStack.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 10
  }));
});
```

But this map function returns an error: `Required argument (collection) missing to function: Image.reduceRegions(image, collection, reducer, scale, crs, crsTransform, tileScale)...`

How can I adjust my mapping function to produce monthly tile means that export?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First, instead of your function `newCollectionToImage()` which is really slow because you are using `.iterate()`, use `.toBands()`.

```
//Apply the function to create a stack of images
var droughtImageStack = drought_M_rename.toBands();
```

Then, also make sure that you set an appropriate scale during `reduceRegions()`.
TerraClimate has a resolution of 2.5 arc minutes, which would be about 4.5 km at the equator, so let's try it like this.

```
tchImg.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    collection: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 4500
  });
```

If this doesn't work, have a look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390655/earth-engine-feature-collection-will-not-export-even-in-chunks/390713#390713) for an example on how to use map with `.reduceRegions()`. Edit: Just realized, that the answer I linked you is an answer to another one of your questions, so this might be not help you much.