# Concatenate image ID to band names for image point sample (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

I am trying to download a point sample of climate information from the TerraClimate collection in GEE. I want the column names to be the concatenation of image ID and band name (a wide table).

I tried with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393724/mapping-over-a-reduceregions-command-in-earth-engine), but this is for one band, and I want the 14 bands of TerraClimate.

`Error: Collection.iterate: Error in map(ID=200005): Image.rename: The number of names (1) must match the number of bands (14). (Error code: 3)`

I get this:

[image: Currently Names]

I want something like this:

`aet_201801`

This is the [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9a017701910191e52993a868ce8a2605)

```js
var points = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-jemora3/assets/points_all");

var drought_M = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE")//.select("pdsi")
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'));

//This function creates a stack of images from the image collection
function newCollectionToImage(collection){
    var stack = ee.Image(collection.iterate(function(img, prev) {
        return ee.Image(prev).addBands(img);
    }, ee.Image(1)));
 
    stack = stack.select(ee.List.sequence(1, stack.bandNames().size().subtract(1)));
    return stack;
}

//This function renames the image collection bands
//var drought_M_rename = drought_M.map(function(img){
//var y = ee.String(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).get("year"));
//return img.set("year",y).rename(y);
//});

//Apply the function to create a stack of images
var droughtImageStack = newCollectionToImage(drought_M);

var table_masked_index = droughtImageStack
      .sampleRegions({
        // Get the sample from the points FeatureCollection.
        collection: points,
        // Properties from the points collection to pass on to the sampled info
        properties: ['id'],
        // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the FeatureCollection.
        scale: 30,
        tileScale: 8,
        geometries: true
      });

// Export table as csv
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table_masked_index,
    description: 'TerraClimate',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ImageCollection.toBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-tobands) function will create an image stack from a collection of images where the new band names are the concatenation of image ID ([`ee.Image.id`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-id)) and original band names, separated by an underscore. After you apply [`ee.Image.sample`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-sample) the resulting table will have columns names like `201801_aet`, `201801_def`, etc (for [TerraClimate](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_TERRACLIMATE) data).

```js
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'));

var imgColStack = imgCol.toBands();

var pointsFc = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-121.25, 39.55]), {'id': 0}),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-120.29, 38.53]), {'id': 1})
]);

var imgSamp = imgColStack.sampleRegions({
    collection: pointsFc,
    properties: ['id'],
    scale: imgCol.first().projection().nominalScale(),
    geometries: true
});

print(imgSamp.first());
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is so elegant, perfect.